# Enum type missing in Entity Framework 6 in Visual Studio 2015

Tags: visual-studio-2015, entity-framework-6

I am following a tutorial in a MS press book. Pretty simple. Setting up an entity model with a model first approach. It instructed to create a `FavoriteColor` scalar as an `int32`, then right click on that property in the model diagram and choose "convert to enum" in the context menu.

But that item is missing from the list. It's not grayed out, just missing. Also, `Enum` type is missing in the model browser under the model:

[image]

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

So I realized if I generate the database from the model, then the convert to enum is in the context menu.  Not sure why.  Maybe that will help someone.  If someone knows why, please enlighten.  thanks!